# Caliburn.Micro - is it possible bind event to System.Action or any other delegate?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, delegates, caliburn.micro

Question as above, short example:

ViewModel

```
public System.Action SomeAction;

private void Function1() {}
private void Function2() {}

//in code somewhere
SomeAction = new System.Action(Function1);
//in code elsewhere
SomeAction = new System.Action(Function2);
```

View

```
xmlns:cm="..."
<Button ...
    cm:Message.Attach=[Event Click] = [Action SomeAction()] />
```

Is something like that possible with Caliburn.Micro? I think it will be suitable in some kind of situations, but code like above throws an exception (MethodNotFound), which is not much a surprise.

Or maybe it's bad approach based on my lack of knowledge and things like that should be done other way?

Answer (score -1):

Just create a public method named `SomeAction()` and that should do the work. In my experience, I haven't really used the old school `delegates` to invoke a `function`. What specific purpose are you trying to achieve here and the reason why you wanted to use the old school `delegate`?

And when are you going to set the delegate to a method? Based on a selected item? business logic? If you really need to do a different action on a different scenario then I think it would be a `design decision` and if you can give me your situation then I can provide more details.

Comment: How could that work? The point is I want to use different functions (based on my choice) reacting to the same event, so no that will not work. What do you mean by "old school delegates"? What are new school delegates? I'm aware I could take another approach to this problem and design it completely other way, I'm just asking if thing like that is possible, or how it should be handled (if this approach is wrong).